# Which module settings should be used in jsconfig.json for importing package to background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, svelte, deepl

I've been trying to implement translation functionality for my chrome extension using the DeepL node API. I've been getting the following error in chrome://extensions.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

[Error message] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4cl.png)

This seems to be a relatively common issue but none of the solutions I've found online have worked.
I am currently using the module and target ESNext in jsconfig.json. I've tried a number of different config settings aswell as using webpack to bundle my modules. Nothing has worked so far.

Here's some relevant code:

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    /**
     * svelte-preprocess cannot figure out whether you have
     * a value or a type, so tell TypeScript to enforce using
     * `import type` instead of `import` for Types.
     */
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    /**
     * To have warnings / errors of the Svelte compiler at the
     * correct position, enable source maps by default.
     */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    /**
     * Typecheck JS in `.svelte` and `.js` files by default.
     * Disable this if you'd like to use dynamic types.
     */
    "checkJs": true
  },
  /**
   * Use global.d.ts instead of compilerOptions.types
   * to avoid limiting type declarations.
   */
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte", "background.ts"]
  

}
```

background.js

```
import * as deepl from 'deepl-node';

const authKey = "hidden"; // REMEMBER TO HIDE
const translator = new deepl.Translator(authKey);

const chromeTab = {
  id: 0,
  url: ""
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "1",
  title: "Translate \"%s\"",
  contexts: ["selection"],
});

let newTabId = null;

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
  newTabId = tab.id;
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "1" && tab) {
    const toTranslate = info.selectionText || "";
    const translatedText = Translate(toTranslate);

    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
      active: true,
    }, (newTab) => {
      const checkNewTabInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (newTab && newTab.id !== undefined) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, { action: "updateTranslation", text: translatedText, taskId: newTab.id }, () => {
            console.log("Message sent!");
          });

          clearInterval(checkNewTabInterval);
        }
      }, 100);
    });
  }
});

function Translate(TextToTranslate) {
  const translation = translator.translateText(TextToTranslate, null, 'es');
  return translation;
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "SweetTranslator",
  "description": "This is for TRANSLATING",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage","activeTab", "contextMenus", "action"],
  
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build-vite": "vite build",
    "build:android": "vite build --mode android --base /assets/ && node script/after-build.js",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.3",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.251",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "svelte": "^3.49.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "vite": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@unocss/reset": "^0.46.5",
    "@unocss/transformer-directives": "^0.46.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^2.1.0",
    "deepl-node": "^1.11.0",
    "svelte-spa-router": "^3.3.0",
    "terser": "^5.15.0",
    "unocss": "^0.46.5",
    "vite-plugin-pages-svelte": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Would very much appreaciate tips, this is my first experience with chrome extensions and JavaScript.

Comment: Judging by the error you loaded the original non-compiled source in the browser, but you must load the output/dist/build folder. If you already did that, then your build config is wrong and I guess the solution is to use separate build entries for the popup and for background.js as these run in two different contexts.

Comment: What do you mean by having two separate build entries? @wOxxOm

Comment: I didn't use vite, so please refer to [these examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=vite+multiple+entries).